# postgresql library not found from within clojure-based docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, jdbc, clojure

I'm running a clojure application which needs to access a local database. The clojure application is using jdbc:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 ...
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.12"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.3.3"]]
```

The application works as expected when run directly on a host with a version of postgresql installed, even when connecting to a remote database.

However, when run from within a docker container based on the `clojure` image:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   
FROM clojure
WORKDIR /ui-service
COPY . .
CMD ["lein", "ring", "server-headless", "3000"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

It fails to connect:

```
lan-activity-ui-service-1  | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz3.so.4)
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |            QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |            QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |             QueryExecutorImpl.java:355 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                   PgStatement.java:490 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                   PgStatement.java:408 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |           PgPreparedStatement.java:166 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |           PgPreparedStatement.java:118 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1090 clojure.java.jdbc/execute-query-with-params
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1084 clojure.java.jdbc/execute-query-with-params
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1113 clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset*
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1093 clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset*
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1182 clojure.java.jdbc/query
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1144 clojure.java.jdbc/query
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1160 clojure.java.jdbc/query
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          jdbc.clj:1144 clojure.java.jdbc/query
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                              db.clj:33 ui-service.db/all-devices
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                              db.clj:32 ui-service.db/all-devices
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                         handler.clj:21 ui-service.handler/fn
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                         handler.clj:20 ui-service.handler/fn
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:158 compojure.core/wrap-response[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:128 compojure.core/wrap-route-middleware[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:137 compojure.core/wrap-route-info[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:146 compojure.core/wrap-route-matches[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:185 compojure.core/routing[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          core.clj:2701 clojure.core/some
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          core.clj:2692 clojure.core/some
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:185 compojure.core/routing
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:182 compojure.core/routing
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                        RestFn.java:139 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:667 clojure.core/apply
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:660 clojure.core/apply
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           core.clj:192 compojure.core/routes[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           json.clj:102 ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-params[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           json.clj:143 ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-response[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                            cors.clj:47 jumblerg.middleware.cors/allow-origins
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                            cors.clj:41 jumblerg.middleware.cors/allow-origins
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                            cors.clj:57 jumblerg.middleware.cors/wrap-cors[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           Var.java:384 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                          reload.clj:39 ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                      stacktrace.clj:26 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-log[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                      stacktrace.clj:96 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-web[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                           jetty.clj:25 ring.adapter.jetty/proxy-handler[fn]
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                       (Unknown Source) ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                 HandlerWrapper.java:97 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                        Server.java:499 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                   HttpChannel.java:311 org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                HttpConnection.java:258 org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |            AbstractConnection.java:544 org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |              QueuedThreadPool.java:635 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |              QueuedThreadPool.java:555 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run
lan-activity-ui-service-1  |                        Thread.java:833 java.lang.Thread.run
```

How can I ensure the required dependencies are available within the docker container? Do I need to use a multi-stage docker build to include the postgresql image? Or is it possible to add the required dependencies purely in java/clojure?

I was able to build a container including the `/usr/lib/postgresql/13/` directory and the `/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so` file that clojure was looking for, but weirdly I still get the error: `ERROR: could not load library &quot;/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so&quot;`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   
FROM postgres:13 as postgres

FROM clojure
WORKDIR /ui-service
COPY . .
COPY --from=postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/ /usr/lib/postgresql/
RUN ls -l /usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so
CMD ["lein", "ring", "server-headless", "3000"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is possible to pull in dependencies over the network from Clojure using tools like [Pomegranate](https://github.com/clj-commons/pomegranate), and a similar capability is available in the alpha releases of Clojure 1.12 itself, it is probably a lot simpler to just build your own container that adds the necessary dependencies to the one you are using.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have a Dockerfile example of how to set this up? Would it be advisable to use a debian/ubuntu image and then `apt-get` install both clojure and postgres? Or is it possible to use a multi-stage build using different `FROM` images?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have any pointers for the pomegranate approach?

Comment: I was able to build a container including the `/usr/lib/postgresql/13/` directory and the `/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so` file that clojure was looking for, but weirdly I still get the error: `ERROR: could not load library &quot;/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

I have [a demo project](https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next) that shows how to use both Postgres and H2 via Docker container from Clojure. It uses the `jdbc.next` library.

Note that we are running Postgres in a Docker container.  This demo runs Clojure from the command line.  Of course, you could also run Clojure in a container, as long as it can access Postgres over port 5432 as normal.

Leiningen is used as normal to define the Clojure project and its dependencies:

```clj
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :dependencies [
                 [com.h2database/h2 "1.4.200"] ; #todo cannot upgrade yet or crash!
                 [hikari-cp "3.0.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [org.clojure/test.check "1.1.1"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.6.0"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.4.1"]
                 [seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.2.659"] ; #todo try porsas
                 [tupelo "23.07.04"]
                 ]

  :plugins      [[com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.25.0"]
                 [lein-ancient "0.7.0"]
                 ]

<snip>
)
```

A short BASH script kicks off Postgres:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

docker run --rm  --name pg-docker  --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker  --detach  --publish 5432:5432  \
  -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data    postgres:14
```

and then run the demo using `lein`:

```bash
> lein clean ; lein test

-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 17.0.1
-----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-h2

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-postgres

Ran 7 tests containing 42 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

See the README for full details.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for me because my intention is to run clojure from docker and communicate with an external postgresql servier via a JDBC client (exteranl server may be in the host or in another docker container). The thing is that the clojure JDBC client appears to fail if some postgresql shared libraries are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was seeing had nothing to do with the JDBC client, it was a server-side error, which may be related to a bullseye -> bookworm upgrade on the server. JDBC Postgresql is indeed a pure-java client and does not need to look up a non-java shared library.

The problem happened after a debian bullseye -> bookworm migration and was resolved by restarting the postgresql server.